# Crontab задача kubernetes возвращает "kubectl: command not found"

Tags: linux, crontab, kubernetes

Следующая команда выполняется без ошибок в терминале:

```
kubectl logs -l app=nodejs > /home/ubuntu/logs/nodejs.log
```

но когда я добавляю ее в crontab

```
*/1 * * * *    kubectl logs -l app=nodejs > /home/ubuntu/logs/nodejs.log
```

я получаю ошибку `/bin/sh: 1: kubectl: not found`

Кто-нибудь знает, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А в какой папке лежит `kubectl`? Не в домашней ли папке пользователя?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov kubectl лежит в /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Comment: все до меня дошло!) /usr/local/bin/kubectl logs -l app=nodejs > /home/ubuntu/logs/nodejs.log
работает

Comment: Если Вы решили проблему, опишите ее решение в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Антон,

Проблема была решена следующим образом:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/kubectl logs -l app=nodejs > /home/ubuntu/logs/nodejs.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос всплывает регулярно. Проблема заключается в том, что авторы таких вопросов забывают о том, что когда они запускают некую программу из командной строки, то она запускается в окружении данного конкретного пользователя.

А когда та же программа запускается *cron*-ом, то и программное окружение наследуется от *cron*-а. И в этих двух **разных** программных окружениях имеются две **разные** переменные *PATH*.

Соответственно, одна и та же программа может быть найдена по пути поиска пользователя и может и не быть найдена по пути поиска *cron*-а.